# Use just part of the input field with CSS

Tags: html, css, input-field

I have an input field, and inside it on the right side there is a string that displays information to the user.

```
<div class="my_div_class">
    <input class="my_input_class" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="my_span_class">6000 available</span>
</div>
```

Using position relative and absolute, I places the span inside the input field.

However, if the user types a long query, the text will be under the span text.

Is there a way to force the input field to do the horizontal scroll when the user reaches a point before the right margin, ideally without using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some `padding-right` to the input box.

```css
.my_div_class {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.my_input_class {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.my_span_class {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_div_class">
  <input class="my_input_class" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <span class="my_span_class">6000 available</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! In my example I had to add a combination of width and padding-right. Just by adding padding-right, the input field was simply growing to the right and the issue was still there.

Comment: @Bruno I also used box-sizing: border-box; in the example, so padding and borders will be part of the total width and height, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
.my_input_class {
  padding-right: 1em; // Replace `1em` with the desired amount of padding
}
```